# Path to configuration files changes between environments in multi-project solution

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, .net-5

I have a multi-project solution where 1 parent project is shared with 3 child projects.

Each child project has its own Program.cs and need to load several shared json files from my parent project.

When I build and publish my project to Azure app service on **linux** all my files get moved to "home/site/wwwroot/Properties" and I can easily load them as if I only had one project:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                //Parent Project Properties
                config.AddJsonFile("Properties/appsettings.json", optional: false);
                config.AddJsonFile("Properties/ParentProjectConfig.json", optional: false);
                
                //Child Project Properties
                config.AddJsonFile("Properties/ChildProjectConfig.json", optional: false);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```

But when I run my project locally, application tries to load the files by their path in the solution:

```
C:\Users\Me\MySolution\ParentProject\Properties\ParentProjectConfig.json
```

Therefore I have to specify what project to load them from like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                var sharedProjectPath = Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).FullName;

                config.SetBasePath(sharedProjectPath);
                
                //Parent Project Properties
                config.AddJsonFile("ParentProject/Properties/appsettings.json", optional: false);
                config.AddJsonFile("ParentProject/Properties/ParentProjectConfig.json", optional: false);
                
                //Child Project Properties
                config.AddJsonFile("ChildProject/Properties/ChildProjectConfig.json", optional: false);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```

I could work around the issue by putting a huge fat

```
if ( /* Running on Azure */ )
{
}
else
{
}
```

in my ConfigureAppConfiguration, but that does not seem very clean. Do you have any suggestions on how files can be loaded using the same code in both environments?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could try to use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` to check if the environment is production or development.

Then you could recode your codes to write the logic to use different ConfigureAppConfiguration method to check if this is environment is production or development, if this environment is production, then you could use first part of codes, if this environment is development, you could use second part of codes.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
                if (environment == "Development")
                {

                }

                if (environment == "Production")
                {

                }
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

To set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Result:

[image]